# how to not elementwise multiple matrices in function subs MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have this:

```
syms X Y;
F=X*Y;
A=ones(2);
B=ones(2);
```

Why `subs (F,{X,Y},{A,B}) == ones(2)?`

How can i get `2*ones(2)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a start, to intialise `X` and `Y` as symbolic matrices

```
X=sym('X',[2 2]);
Y=sym('Y',[2 2]);
```

Comment: and how now get `2*ones(2)`? `subs (F,{X,Y},{A,B})` is not working

Comment: `X=sym('X',[2 2]);`   
`Y=sym('Y',[2 2]);`   
`f=X*Y;`   
`A=ones(2);`   
`B=ones(2);`   
`subs(f,{X,Y},{A,B});`   
`ans =
 
[ X1_1*Y1_1 + X1_2*Y2_1, X1_1*Y1_2 + X1_2*Y2_2]
[ X2_1*Y1_1 + X2_2*Y2_1, X2_1*Y1_2 + X2_2*Y2_2]`

Comment: how to insert A and B?

Comment: Each element of `X` and `Y` is called `Xi_j` where `i` is the row and `j` is the column. You will have to substitute each value individually. Why re you doing this, why not just do `ones(2)^2`?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug, however here is a simple work around.  Like David said, initialize `X` and `Y` as matrices

```
X=sym('X',[2 2]);
Y=sym('Y',[2 2]);
```

After that you need to use two substitutions as sometimes Matlab struggles with 'vectorized'  inputs into symbolic expressions.

```
F = X*Y;
A = ones(2);
B = ones(2);
FA = subs(F, X, A);
FAB = subs(FA, X, B);
```